# How to iterate over time periods in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider I have a pandas `Series` with a `DatetimeIndex` with daily frequency. I want to iterate over this `Series` with arbitrary frequency and an arbitrary look-back window. For example: Iterate half-yearly with a lookback window of 1y.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
for df_year in df.timegroup(freq='6m', lookback='1y'):
   # df_year will span one year of daily prices and be generated every 6 months
```

I know about `TimeGrouper` but haven't figured out how it could do this. Anyway, I could just code this manually but was hoping for a clever `pandas` one-liner.

Edit:
This is getting a bit closer:

```
pd.rolling_apply(df, 252, lambda s: s.sum(), freq=pd.datetools.BMonthEnd())
```

This doesn't quite work, because it applies a lookback window of 252*BMonthEnd() while I'd like that to be independent and have a lookback window of 252 **days** every end of the month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

Construct a series of a frequency. Using 1 for clarify here.

```
In [77]: i = pd.date_range('20110101','20150101',freq='B')

In [78]: s = Series(1,index=i)

In [79]: s
Out[79]: 
2011-01-03    1
2011-01-04    1
2011-01-05    1
2011-01-06    1
2011-01-07    1
             ..
2014-12-26    1
2014-12-29    1
2014-12-30    1
2014-12-31    1
2015-01-01    1
Freq: B, dtype: int64

In [80]: len(s)
Out[80]: 1044
```

Conform the index to another frequency. This makes every index element be the end-of-month here.

```
In [81]: s.index = s.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')

In [82]: s
Out[82]: 
2011-01-31    1
2011-01-31    1
2011-01-31    1
2011-01-31    1
2011-01-31    1
             ..
2014-12-31    1
2014-12-31    1
2014-12-31    1
2014-12-31    1
2015-01-31    1
dtype: int64
```

Then its straightforward to resample to another frequency. This gives you the number of business days in the period in this case.

```
In [83]: s.resample('3M',how='sum')
Out[83]: 
2011-01-31    21
2011-04-30    64
2011-07-31    65
2011-10-31    66
2012-01-31    66
              ..
2014-01-31    66
2014-04-30    63
2014-07-31    66
2014-10-31    66
2015-01-31    44
Freq: 3M, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I'm a bit confused. In the second chunk you are resampling and the result is a Series of monthly frequency so it would appear that the daily information is lost. Then you resample and somehow the days are there? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: the period -> timestamp conversion changes the days themselves to the month ends, but the order / number is preserved. So when you then sum based on the months you infer that data.

Answer (score 4):

This solution provides a one liner using list comprehension.  Starting from the left of the time series and iterating forward (backward iteration could also be done), the iteration returns a subset of the index equal to the loopback window and jumps in a step size equal to the frequency.  Note that the very last period is likely a stub with a length less than the lookback window.

This method uses days rather than month or week offsets.

```
freq = 30      # Days
lookback = 60  # Days

idx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2015-01-01')
[idx[(freq * n):(lookback + freq * n)] for n in range(int(len(idx) / freq))]

Out[86]: 
[<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
 [2010-01-01, ..., 2010-03-01]
 Length: 60, Freq: D, Timezone: None,
 <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
 [2010-01-31, ..., 2010-03-31]
 Length: 60, Freq: D, Timezone: None,
...
 Length: 60, Freq: D, Timezone: None,
 <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
 [2014-11-06, ..., 2015-01-01]
 Length: 57, Freq: D, Timezone: None]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this!
I ideally this would be datetime aware though. For example, my datetimeindex only goes over business days and I'd like to select the last day of the month with a certain look-back window.

Comment: last day of the month?

Comment: Thanks, updated my comment as well as the question with an example that doesn't quite work yet.

Comment: If you choose the last business day of the month and have a lookback frequency in days, then it would be possible to have multiple periods with overlapping days or days missing.  For example, Feb 28 with a 30 day lookback could include Jan 30/31, whereas Jan Mar 31 with a 30 day lookback could exclude Mar 1.  Is this acceptable for your needs?